# how to write the regular expression for the following details?

Tags: asp.net, regex

How do I write a regular expression which should allow only `[]`, `'`, `/`,`\`, `space`, `+`,`-`,`*`,`()`,`{}`,`&`,`^` and `@`?

i want regular expression which work in dotnet.
Please help me?

Comment: Why use a regex and not simple character matching?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
/[[\]'/\\@ ]+/
```

---

[Explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%2F%5B%5B%5C%5D%27%2F%5C%5C%40+%5D%2B%2F)

```
  NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [[\]'/\\@ ]+             any character of: '[', '\]', ''', '/',
                           '\\', '@', ' ' (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
```

**Notes:**

- `\]` is escaped because it appears inside a bracket (`[]`) pair
- `\\` is escaped because `\` is the escape character

---

Update per your comment

```
/[[\]'/\\@ &(){}+$%#=~"-]+/
```

Comment: you probably don't want to include the outer / characters, depending on how you're instantiating the regex

Comment: Can u explain the above expression?

Comment: @CupawnTae `/` is just a standard delimiter for most flavors of regular expressions.

Comment: @maček sure, but the question specifically mentioned .net, which generally doesn't use that syntax, so I thought it worth mentioning

Comment: i want to allow some characters like &,(),{},/,-,+,$,%,#,=,~,""

Comment: hi macek please help me to allow the above characters also.

Comment: @Srinivas, I updated this, but this is just becoming a "you do it for me" type of question. I got you started, do a little more reading, and carry yourself the rest of the way. I.e., if you know how to allow `A`, you should know how to allow `B` and `C`.

Comment: sorry i forgot some characters those are *,`,~,^.please give reply

Comment: k @Macek i have tried with ur validation if i give ! this symbol it is alos accepting

Comment: i do not wont to allow that symbol.

Answer (score 0):

To match 1 or more of the characters:

```
[[\]'/\\@ ]+
```

To also match the empty string, change the + to a *, i.e.

```
[[\]'/\\@ ]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out for C#.NET:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string txt=",'/\\ @";

  string re1=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
  string re2="(@)"; // Any Single Character 1

  Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
  Match m = r.Match(txt);
  if (m.Success)
  {
        String c1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
        Console.Write("("+c1.ToString()+")"+"\n");
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)